# Ionic - disable view transition animation but only for single view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, transition

How can I disable transition animation for a certain view completely?

I do not want to:

- disable for the whole app with configuration
- use navTransition directive which simply hacks the next transition and works only on element when clicked: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/e2727d2e8f0815c3418e1fc29c92e2180e513408/js/angular/directive/navTransition.js

Ideally I am looking for an attribute to set on `ion-view` or `ion-nav-view`

Answer (score 1):

`ui-view` supports `noanimation="..."`, but it doesn't work in *ionic*

The only thing I could find was:

HTML

```
<ion-nav-view>
  <link ng-href="css/styleSlide.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

styleSlide.css

```
/* untested */
[nav-view-transition="ios"] [nav-view="entering"],
[nav-view-transition="ios"] [nav-view="leaving"] {
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0ms;
  transition-duration: 0ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from **malix** is a step in good direction, however there is no need for such conditional css. What I ended up using is an id on the ion-view element and I used:

```
#header-sub-content ion-view[nav-view="entering"] {
  transition-duration: 0ms;
} 

#header-sub-content ion-view[nav-view="leaving"] {
  transition-duration: 0ms;
}
```

However, this leaves a slightly strange flicker effect which I didn't bother to solve because what I acually needed is to hide the animation which is leaving and only show the one which "enters":

```
#header-sub-content ion-view[nav-view="entering"] {
    display: block;
} 

#header-sub-content ion-view[nav-view="leaving"] {
    display: none;
}
```